# Making Magic Fairy Dust With JQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, canvas, processing.js

I have the following task:

**Add falling fairy dust (kind of like Tinker Bell) to a website logo.**

The falling fairy dust should be continuously animated/falling and fading out.

The website logo is a png.

I would like to absolutely position a div over the existing website logo image. That div would contain the animating fairy dust.

I know this is usually the type of job for Flash, but it is not allowed for this project.

**What is the best way to do this? 
Is there some way with JQuery animation, or Canvas or processing.js?**

Answer (score 3):

of course you could use javascript to add some dust, but this will strain the browser/system quite a bit.

i think the easiest way would be to create a gif with falling fairy dust and put it on top of your logo

ie.: a falling snow gif [a falling snow gif](http://www.animationlibrary.com/animation/29833/White_snow/)

Comment: +1.  Unless the animation needs to cover more than just the logo, it would be hard to compete with the simplicity of a pre-rendered animated GIF.  Using jQuery would be more technically interesting, though.  :)